# Using recursion to reduce digits of a number

Tags: python, recursion, recursionerror

I am working through a coding challenge and I'm using this problem as a way to get myself used to recursion. The problem gives me an integer n that is of any length and my job is to sum all the digits until it becomes a single digit number and then output the number of times that took place.

To illustrate, lets just say the value is 87559:

```
8+7+5+5+9 = 34
3 + 4 = 7
```

So the return value is 2.  If n was `1,000,000`, the return would be 1.

I felt like this was a recursion problem so I tried to get that part working first. This is my code:

```
def digitDegree(n):
    
    return digitDegree(sum(map(int, str(n)))
```

However, this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  main.py3 in the pre-written template, in getUserOutputs
    userOutput = _runlnlao(testInputs[i])
  main.py3 in the pre-written template, in _runlnlao
    return digitDegree(*_fArgs_qeqrszlgdnyi)
  main.py3 on line 13, in digitDegree
    return digitDegree(sum(map(int, str(n))))
  main.py3 on line 13, in digitDegree
    return digitDegree(sum(map(int, str(n))))
  main.py3 on line 13, in digitDegree
    return digitDegree(sum(map(int, str(n))))
  [Previous line repeated 9993 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

Comment: You need a base case where the recursion ends otherwise how would it ever stop? Maybe a good base case is when the length of the number is 1.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes, I commented before the new edit came up.  Yes, *we* can do it in one step, but OP should likely take the more conventional route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why you *always* start with the base cases: you have to stop the recursion somewhere.  Back up to your basics on recursion:

- How do you know when you're done?
- What do you return in that base case?
- When you transition from a recursion step back to its parent, what information do you need to accumulate?

Those three items will get you to the solution.

Coding is left as an exercise for the student.  :-)

Comment: Answer the first question above.  You seem to be asking for individual tutorial help in problem analysis and coding; this is too broad for Stack Overflow.  Do the problem on paper: how do *you* know when to stop?

Comment: Well, its up there, no?  Its done when the number is a single digit.

Comment: Exactly -- so you should have added that to your code already.

Comment: That's what I am asking for! How do I use recursion to reduce my values to a single digit?

Comment: My answer gives you the steps for handling recursion.  You already detailed how to reduce the number to a single digit.  Where are you stuck?  So far, your question seems to reduce to "write the code for me", which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2):

you can do it like this & 'times' will show you the number of times recursion occurred

```
def recurtion_function(x):
    global times
    times += 1
    num = 0
    while x != 0:
        num += x % 10
        x = x // 10
    if num > 10:
        recurtion_function(num)

var = int(input("enter the number:"))
times = 0
recurtion_function(var)
print(times)
```

Comment: There is no point in giving the answer to a question that's meant for learning.